# MFMessageComposeViewController on Simulator - canSendText?

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator, sendmessage

following situation: I want to send in app SMS. This is my code creating the MFMessageComposeViewController:

```
-(void) showMessageComposerWithText:(NSString*)messageText telNumber:(NSString*)telNumber composeDelegate:(id)delegate
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {   
        controller.body = messageText;
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:telNumber];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = delegate;

        [delegate presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

So I think this is straight forward. When testing in Simulator I get following exception: `Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x8a4e090>`. I'm also wondering myself why `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` returns `YES` when running the app in the simulator.

When running on the device, everything is working correctly.

I couldn't find anything in the docs/web concerning this strange behavior.

I'm running Xcode 4.3 on OS 10.7.3, Deployment Target is iOS 5.0.

Thanks in advance,
tubtub

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This problem occurs when you install Messages beta on OS X Lion.

Edit: It also occurs on Mountain Lion when there is an iMessage account configured and enabled. If the account is disabled, it works correctly (canSendText returns NO).

Tip: If you use `controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`, you can  go back in Simulator by clicking on the curled "page" in the upper left corner.

Comment: If Messages beta installed, `canSendText` returns `YES`, but view will become black and empty (no content). If Messages beta uninstalled, `canSendText` returns `NO`. Xcode 4.4 GM and iPhone 5.1 Simulator on Lion.

Comment: Any fix for this yet? This bug persists on Mac OS 10.8.2 with XCode 4.6.1.

Answer (score 4):

The simulator should always return NO from the canSendText, this isn't the case for the iOS 5.0 and 5.1 simulators. With Xcode 4.2 it crashed, on Xcode 4.3 it just pushes a nil view controller.

Comment: Im having the same issue, that a nil view is being pushed but it is even happening on my test device an iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same thing. I think it's a bug in the iOS 5 simulator with Xcode 4.3. `canSendText` correctly returns `NO` in the iOS 4.3 simulator. The same code works fine on the device.

Answer (score 1):

With this configuration, canSendText returns correctly NO in the simulator (plus, a UIAlertView appears to say text messaging is not available):

- Mountain Lion
- Xcode 4.4,
- iOS 5.1

Comment: I guess you don't have iMessage account configured and enabled.