# Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x96d1380>

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, presentmodalviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Has anybody encountered this kind of error in `MFMessageComposeViewController`?

I allocated and presented it like this:

```
    MFMessageComposeViewController *message = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    message.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:message animated:YES];
```

but it presents an empty view and says:

`Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x96d1380>.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [MFMessageComposeViewController on Simulator - canSendText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349381/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-on-simulator-cansendtext)

Basically this occurs in the simulator on Lion and Mountain Lion if it has a Messages account enabled. Try testing on a real device as it should work okay there.

Comment: Actually, I have tested in device and it work. I remember on the previous xcode versions opening the iMessage on simulator make it crash and now will display white view.