# MFMessageComposeViewController shows blank/white screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller.body = @"This is a test!";

    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:phones];

    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This code makes the entire screen white/blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349381/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-on-simulator-cansendtext

Comment: @Shashank testing on device, not simulator.

Comment: Can you print whats there in phones ?

Answer (score 3):

Problem was in this line:

```
controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:phones];
```

It was a malformed phone # array. Not sure why the malformed phone # didn't raise an error, but filtering it out fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't understand. What did you filter? I have the same kind of problem, but it comes only some percent of the time, while other time works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same problem and found my mistake.

Make sure the phone numbers you send to controller.recipients are NSString. I have sent some long NSInteger and it goes to blank screen.