# ios : sms message composer not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactionsheet, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have a UITableViewController presenting a list of contacts, when the user selects a row, it'll show a UIActionSheet to ask the user an action (call, send sms...).

The user selects an action, and that first UIActionSheet will show another UIActionSheet which contains phone numbers.

The user selects a phone number, and this should show the SMS message composer.

The problem is that when the user selects a phone number, the message composer view doesn't show (just a black screen), and I receive the MessageComposeResultCancelled in the MFMessageComposeViewController's didFinishWithResult.

Which generates this warning "Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"

How can I correctly call and show the SMS message composer?

(this works perfectly if I call it directly when the user selects a row in the list with didSelectRowAtIndexPath)

Here's some code :

1- call to first UIActionSheet in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method :

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery;
...
[popupQuery showInView:self.view];
```

2- call to second UIActionSheet in clickedButtonAtIndex method :

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery2;
...
[popupQuery showInView:self.view];
```

3- from the same method, call to message composer :

```
[self sendSMS:@"" recipientList:[phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:buttonIndex]];
```

the method that shows message composer :

```
    (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
        controller.recipients = recipients;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code on how you are showing/dismissing your view controllers ? As you can see from the error message, there is a problem with the way they are presented/dismissed.

Comment: Does this occur on an actual iDevice, or has it just been tested on the Simulator?

`canSendText`

Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the current device is capable of sending text messages.
However, `canSendText` may return true on the Simulator as you may have the messages app installed on your Mac (_see additional question http://mby.me/Gw_)

Comment: I'm testing on an iphone 5

Answer (score 1):

solution found here : [MFMessageComposeViewController shows blank/white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138497/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-shows-blank-white-screen)

```
    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:theRecipients];
```

theRecipients was an array containing only one element (the phone number selected)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to try showing two modal controls in the same time, use `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method so that action sheet is hidden when you start to show messaging controller.

The following code shows composer which is not cancelled automatically.
I can see `0` at log which is the value of `MessageComposeResultCancelled`, only when I press  `Cancel` button. Are you trying to make a hack by pressing `send` button automatically ?

[image: composer from action sheet delegate]

**MFMessageComposeViewController.h**

```
enum MessageComposeResult {
    MessageComposeResultCancelled, //0
    MessageComposeResultSent,      //1
    MessageComposeResultFailed     //2
};
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)onButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet * sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Go out"
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Show message composer"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"body";
//        controller.recipients = recipients;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void) messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    NSLog(@"%d", result);
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: the thing is that the app receives "MessageComposeResultCancelled" just after calling the message composer

Comment: @dzk Does it happen when you show composer from `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` ?

Comment: yes, instead of showing the message composer,it shows a blank screen like this http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/7624/screenshot20130302at931.png

Comment: @dzk updated the answer with proof of concept. Please share your delegate method.

Comment: I'm using similar code than A-Live's.
No I'm not trying to simulate the send action. Just showing the message composer. 

Sometimes in logs I have this message too :

- init Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"

- Remote compose controller timed out (NO)!

Comment: I'm doing it from a UITableViewController.

If in the same file, I move the code to the table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath, it works perfectly

Comment: solution found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138497/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-shows-blank-white-screen

Comment: @dzk Interesting, you might want to file a bug.