# How to specify/add receiver's number in MFMessageComposerViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, messageui, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

i have following listing in my code.

```
- (IBAction)sendText:(id)sender {
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *textSheet=[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
    textSheet.messageComposeDelegate=self;
    [textSheet setBody:@"Demonic Possessions"];
    [self presentViewController:textSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}  else  {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Not Supported With Device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

But the receiver's number isn't specified anywhere in the code.

is it possible to send message with MFMessageComposerViewController to a specific contact number ?

if not, then how would i do it?
a code would be very much helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `recipients` property. Set it up with an NSArray of phone numbers as NSStrings.

```
textSheet.recipients = @[@"1234", @"3234"];
```

Comment: it wont work with simulator right ?
i have to use an actual device ?

Comment: This question explains it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349381/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-on-simulator-cansendtext

Comment: Before instantiating the class, always check the canSendText property to be true.